# How to link angularjs component per file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, file, components

I am new to angularjs and I have read in multiple places that we should aim to define one component per file. This works fine when you have few components but as soon as you start to have more than few lets say more than 5 then linking them would be a nightmare. 
Example:-

If I have a controller defined in file1.js

```
angular.module('module-name')
    .controller('controller1', function (service1) {
        return {
            ....
        };
    });
```

and a service defined in another file called file2.js

```
angular.module('module-name')
    .factory('service1', function () {
        return {
            ....
        };
    });
```

Now in my html file I need to include both

```
<script src="file1.js"></script>
<script src="file2.js"></script>
```

and it soon will become a mess.

How do we solve this problem? I am using it in an ASP.NET MVC. Help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: the do bundling on server side and load file in client side http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification?

Comment: do accept answer which I've added and close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using Asp.net c#, you could use server side Bundling & Minification

Enabling bundling on server side by using `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;` in you `Global.asax`

Bundle all the `CSS` & `JS` files in sepearate bundle. After that refer them on `.cshtml` page using

Refer bundled JS files using `@Scripts.Render("bundleName.js")`

For more info [**look at this.**](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification)